# What exactly does Modify/Change do in Windows regarding applications?

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems

Settings: Apps and Features:

[image: Settings | Apps and Features]

Control Panel: Programs and Features

[image: Control Panel | Programs and Features]

Comment: Only large applications like office actually have a modify (eg don't install clip art). Most apps are installed or not installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly does Modify/Change do in Windows regarding applications?

It depends on the application, how it is written, and what it can do with respect to modifications.

Generally the answer to your question is:  Modify / Change often / usually runs the program or the program installer to present a menu to Modify settings if it can (simple programs often cannot); Repair the program (most programs can repair themselves); and possibly Uninstall the program.

Sometimes to Repair a program, you just install it again and that repairs it.

Since it depends on the program (and I have all kinds with all different Change / Modify setups), there is no hard fast answer to your question.

The general approach I laid out is as close as it gets.

By way of example only, Office allows Repair or Uninstall, whereas Tree Size offers only uninstall.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows provides functionality for application developers to install their application and potentially allow the end user to modify or uninstall the application.

When installing an application the developer can choose if they want it to appear in the list of installed applications, and if so, what functionality is offered to the user.

The minimum fields that should be set in the registry during install are described in the following post: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040709-00/?p=38493

So the only mandated values when adding an entry are "DisplayName" and the "UninstallPath". There are plenty of others, for example, "SystemComponent" (DWORD), is another example, which if set to 1, will hide the application from the list.

If you view some of the values under the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

...you will get the general idea as to what options are possible for a given installed application. Programs and Features uses these registry values directly to form the list and detail the properties seen.

Here is a manually added example:
[image: Example registry]

Given the entries in the registry example above, Programs and Features will offer uninstall and modify for the application listed as "A test app".  When the user chooses "Modify", it will launch calc.exe and when choosing "Uninstall" it will run charmap.exe. If "NoModify" was changed to a 1. Modify will not be offered.

This is a basic test case. It gets more complicated with MSI based installers where Windows Installer processes the MSI file. It really depends on what workflows the developer has in mind for the application.